# My baby is so Clinging

Tags: parents

My one year old boy baby is so clingy.It’s too stressful.Always he would like to be in kitchen.I tried to divert him in all ways but he always wish to be in kitchen.He is not playing with toys.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite normal for a 1 year old to be clingy. A child that age will always want to be as close as possible to his parent all of the time.

A common trick is to allow the child to play with some pots and pans on the kitchen floor. He'll be happy because he's near you, but hopefully won't be too much in your way.

If you are finding it stressful to be near him so much then perhaps you could reach out for assistance from your support network, friends, relatives etc.

Comment: Using a papoose can also help them be close but not getting in your way too much.